# Is this best practive for schedule and unschedule when moving sprite?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

Just wondering if this is the best solution for me to control my sprites movement with a custom joystick.

```
//Move Up
if (bDegree < 45 && btocLength > 50) {
    [self unschedule:@selector(movePlayerRight)];
    [self unschedule:@selector(movePlayerDown)];
    [self unschedule:@selector(movePlayerLeft)];
    [self schedule:@selector(movePlayerUp)];
    [self schedule:@selector(isPlayerWalking:) interval:1.0f/11.0f];
}
```

It just seems that my Debug area in xcode goes crazy when I use this style of scheduling. Does this matter? Thoughts?

**Debug Area**

```
2013-06-15 10:03:59.866 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:03:59.875 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 178.148285
2013-06-15 10:03:59.877 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:03:59.924 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 177.795670
2013-06-15 10:03:59.928 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:03:59.949 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:03:59.953 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0909 to 0.0909
2013-06-15 10:03:59.988 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 177.425034
2013-06-15 10:04:00.117 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:04:00.120 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0909 to 0.0909
2013-06-15 10:04:00.854 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 177.795670
2013-06-15 10:04:00.920 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 178.148285
2013-06-15 10:04:00.922 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:04:00.982 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 178.519455
2013-06-15 10:04:00.985 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:04:00.989 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:04:00.990 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0909 to 0.0909
2013-06-15 10:04:01.061 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 178.890228
2013-06-15 10:04:01.092 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 178.898911
2013-06-15 10:04:01.095 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:04:01.107 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 178.903717
2013-06-15 10:04:01.109 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:04:01.124 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 178.910522
2013-06-15 10:04:01.127 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
2013-06-15 10:04:01.139 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] Degree: 178.930817
2013-06-15 10:04:01.141 AnchorMovement-iOS[9866:907] CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
```

Comment: put that code in the update method, use if/else to perform the directional changes. Selector scheduling is overkill for this.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D tried using the update method because it makes sense but I'm getting the following error.

2013-06-16 09:42:10.002 AnchorMovement-iOS[337:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCScheduler: You can't re-schedule an 'update' selector'. Unschedule it first'

I have the ScheduleUpdate inside a ccTouchMove. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?